# Templated typedef structs with constructor in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, struct, using

I have this code right now, which seems to work so far but I was wondering if there was a way to get the exact same struct in a more elegant way since my method so far needs a duplicate everytime for each struct... The end goal would be to have a typedefed struct which would swap the bytes according to the endianness automatically.

```
using ResourceHeader_t = struct ResourceHeader_s 
{
    uint32_t magic;
    uint32_t chunkVersion;
    uint32_t chunkSize;
};

template<bool bigEndian>
struct ResourceHeader : public ResourceHeader_s 
{
    ResourceHeader(ResourceHeader_t* ptr) : ResourceHeader_s(*ptr)
    {
        if (bigEndian)
        {
            LITTLE_BIG_SWAP(magic);
            LITTLE_BIG_SWAP(chunkVersion);
            LITTLE_BIG_SWAP(chunkSize);
        }
    }
};
```

Usage example :

```
ResourceHeader<true> resourceHeader((ResourceHeader_t *)fileBuffer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a `typedef struct` declaration in C++. This is a relic of C.

In C++, after declaring a `struct ResourceHeader_s`, or `struct ResourceHeader_t`, or just a plain `struct ResourceHeader`, the same symbol can be used directly by itself, without an explicit `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

You might simply add the endianess as a ResourceHeader ctor parameter, rather than a template parameter. This would remove duplicate definitions of the struct (one for big and one not).